# Link physical ip phone with Twilio via SIP

Tags: twilio

I'm attempting to run a physical ip phone with Twillio via SIP and I'm missing something as the connection is not being made.  Here is what I've done.

I setup a phone on twilio with incoming voice "A Call Comes In" set to this TwiMLBin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial answerOnBridge="true">
    <Sip>
      {{To}}@hcs.sip.twilio.com
    </Sip>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Then in Programmable SIP Domains I have setup the SIP URI

```
hcs.sip.twilio.com
```

I have also set:
Voice Authentication with a credential list of username and password.

Call Control Configuration:
A Call Comes in WebHook to http://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice HTTP GET

SIP Registration:
Enabled Credential lists: HCS Usr

Then in the phone I have the following settings.  Excuse the imgs.  Note the myusrid, I actually use an idea, I replaced it just for security reasons.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd7tR.png)
[image]

When I dial the number it says the number has been disconnected.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your SIP Username (username in credential list) is in E.164 format. So + and then country code. Register using this username.

For example:

`+13055551212`

Also, check the [Debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/debugger?quickDate=72) in console, to see the errors.